# How do we verify standard error implementation in a PyTorch-based logistic regression code?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, statistics, gpu, logistic-regression

I am currently implementing a logistic regression code using PyTorch and running it on a GPU. Below, I have provided a portion of the code. Following the model training, my objective is to obtain the coefficients, calculate the standard error (represented by the variable 'se'), p-values, as well as the confidence interval's lower and upper bounds. I have noticed that I am getting p-value of zero for number of a features. I am uncertain if I am correctly calculating the standard error. Could you kindly review my code and provide feedback?

Note: Please offer a solution that does not involve using the 'statsmodels' package. I am doing model training on GPU and do not want to do it for multiple times.

```
losses = []
losses_test = []
Iterations = []
iter = 0
for epoch in tqdm(range(int(num_epochs)), desc='Training Epochs'):
    x = X_train
    labels = y_train
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    outputs = model(X_train)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    
    optimizer.step()

    iter+=1
    if iter%1000==0:
        with torch.no_grad():
            correct_test=0
            total_test=0
            outputs_test=model(X_test)
            loss_test=criterion(outputs_test, y_test)
            predicted_test = outputs_test.round().detach().cpu().numpy()
            
            total_test += y_test.size(0)
            correct_test += np.sum(predicted_test == y_test.detach().cpu().numpy())
             
            accuracy_test = 100 * correct_test/total_test
            losses_test.append(loss_test.item())

            total = 0
            correct = 0 
            total += y_train.size(0)
            correct += np.sum(torch.squeeze(outputs).round().detach().cpu().numpy() == y_train.detach().cpu().numpy())
            
            accuracy = 100 *correct/total
            losses.append(loss.item())
            Iterations.append(iter)

            print(f"Iteration: {iter}. \n Test - Loss: {loss_test.item()}. Accuracy: {accuracy_test}")
            print(f"Train - Loss: {loss.item()}. Accuracy: {accuracy}\n")


coef_estimates = model.linear.weight.detach().cpu().numpy().flatten()

#---Standard error calculation code stats here---#
y_train_new = y_train.view(-1)
y_train_new = y_train_new.cpu().numpy()

y_pred = model(X_train).detach().cpu().numpy().flatten()
residuals = y_train_new - y_pred
residual_var = np.sum(residuals ** 2) / (X_train.shape[0] - X_train.shape[1])

se = np.sqrt(np.diag(np.linalg.pinv(X_train.T.cpu() @ X_train.cpu()) * residual_var))
#---Standard error calculation code ends here---#

if np.any(se == 0):
    z_scores = np.where(se == 0, np.nan, coef_estimates /se)
else:
    z_scores = coef_estimates / se

p_values = 2 * (1 - norm.cdf(np.abs(z_scores)))
z_critical = norm.ppf(1 - 0.025)
ci_low = coef_estimates - z_critical * se
ci_high = coef_estimates + z_critical * se
```